# Find data associated with text element in kinetic javascript in popus

Tags: javascript, jquery, kineticjs

```
var text = new Kinetic.Text({
    x: a,
    y:  b,
    text: {"name":"WAERK","key":"","description":"SD Document Currency"}.name,
    fontSize: d,
    fontFamily: 'Calibri',
    fill: e ,
    id:"text"+textcount++
});
```

On clicking the text element I want "description":"SD Document Currency" in popup please help me.

Answer (score 0):

You have to store the information if you want to retrieve it. For example,

```
var text = new Kinetic.Text({
    x: a,
    y:  b,
    text: "WAERK",
    fontSize: d,
    fontFamily: 'Calibri',
    fill: e ,
    id:"text"+textcount++,
    description: 'SD Document Currency'
});
```

or `text.setAttr('description', description);`. (Note, using the setAttr(s) method allows us to listen for the `descriptionChange` event on the Text object if you ever need to.) You can then retrieve the description with `text.getAttr('description');` or `text.attrs.description;`. Then just pass that into `alert` or whatever pop-up you're using.